# Code style - for with if

Tags: python, coding-style

Which of the three do you think is a better coding style, or more readable? `foo` should be run on the items from both dictionaries, but `mydict2` can be `None`

Option 1:

```
for a,b in mydict1.items():
    foo(a,b) 
if mydict2:
    for a,b in mydict2.items():
        foo(a,b)
```

Option 2:

```
for a,b in mydict1.items():
    foo(a,b)
for a,b in mydict2.items() if mydict2 else dict().items():
    foo(a,b)
```

Option 3:

```
for a,b in chain(mydict1.items(), mydict2.items() if mydict2 else dict().items()):
    foo(a,b)
```

Comment: You know iterating over `mydict2.items()` just won't do anything if it's empty? The ternary expression is completely redundant.

Comment: @jonsharpe But the OP says it could be `None`. Trying to iterate over `None` throws an error.

Comment: @Sam then they should be testing by identity - `if mydict2 is not None`

Answer (score 6):

Detect the side case early on, and replace it with an empty dict - this is the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern):

```
if mydict2 is None:
     mydict2 = {}
```

This is identical to a common pattern used to avoid mutable default arguments. Then you can always have one (very simple) loop:

```
for a, b in chain(mydict.items(), mydict2.items()):
```

If you control the relevant code, consider changing things so that `mydict2` can't be `None` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I like the third option, because the single loop makes the intention of the program clearer. If it were me I'd make a helper generator, in the interest of separating concerns.

```
def mydictitems(*dicts):
    for d in dicts:
         if d:
              yield from d.items()

for a,b in mydictitems(mydict1, mydict2):
    foo(a,b)
```